# Let $A$ be infinite. Show that $A$ is countable iff there exists $f:A \rightarrow N$ which is $1-1$

Tags: real-analysis

I would just like to check if my proof is correct in the direction that if that function exists then $A$ is countable.

We know that $A$ is infinite, then let $A=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. I think stating it like this becomes trivial instantly, so I am not sure if I am allowed to write out set $A$ like that, but I cannot see why not. $1-1$ (injection) implies that each element in the codomain of $f$ gets mapped to at most one element in the domain. Then let us define that function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows: $f(a_n)=n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $A$ is countable.

Am I allowed to set the form of $f$ like I did? I think I am, since the statement says "there exists" and not "for all" (i.e. I am allowed to pick a form of $f$).

Comment: Do you know Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein?

Comment: I didn't. But now I do

Comment: You cannot write $A=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ unless you already know that $A$ is countable.

Comment: Can you find a sequence so that $\mathbb{R} = \left\{ a_n \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Comment: @max Ok, I see why I cannot write it like that now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $A=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ you're already assuming $A$ is countable.

More properly: *a set $A$ is infinite if and only if there exists a 1-1 mapping* $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to A$ (requires some form of the axiom of choice).

If $A$ is infinite and there is also a 1-1 mapping $g\colon A\to\mathbb{N}$, then the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) tells you that $A$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$, that is, it is countable.

Comment: Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem requires a function  $h: \mathbb {N} \rightarrow A$ that is 1-1 for there to exist a bijection. I cannot see how to prove that there is such

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal That map exists because $A$ is infinite.

Comment: but $\mathbb {R }$ is infinite too, and there is no such map

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. There is no 1-1 mapping $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$, but this is the reverse direction and, indeed, $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Comment: I was talking about this direction: $f: \mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$. Also, $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb {Q}$ and yet both are countable.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal And where's the problem? For *every* infinite set $A$ there exists a 1-1 mapping $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to A$.

Comment: yes, precisely. I am trying to figure out why this is the case. Because as I said before, take $\mathbb {R}$ it is infinite. But is there $f: \mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathb{R}$? No, and so there must be something that I am missing

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal 1-1, with other terminology, is *injective*; there is no assumption on it to also be surjective.